# ff package in R: how to move data from one drive to another, and change filenames

Tags: r, ff

I am working intensively with the amazing ff and ffbase package. 
Due to some technical details, I have to work in my C: drive with my R session. After finishing that, I move the generated files to my P: drive (using cut/paste in windows, NOT using ff).

The problem is that when I load the ffdf object:

```
load.ffdf("data")
```

I get the error:

```
Error: file.access(filename, 0) == 0 is not TRUE
```

This is ok, because nobody told the ffdf object that it was moved, but trying :

```
filename(data$x) <- "path/data_ff/x.ff"
```

or

```
pattern(data) <- "./data_ff/"
```

does not help, giving the error:

```
Error in `filename<-.ff`(`*tmp*`, value = filename) : 
ff file rename from 'C:/DATA/data_ff/id.ff' to 'P:/DATA_C/data_ff/e84282d4fb8.ff' failed.
```

Is there any way to "change" into the ffdf object the path for the files new location? 
Thank you !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to 'correct' your filenames afterwards you can use:

```
physical(x)$filename <- "newfilename"
```

For example:

```
> a <- ff(1:20, vmode="integer", filename="./a.ff")
> saveRDS(a, "a.RDS")
> rm(a)
> file.rename("./a.ff", "./b.ff")
[1] TRUE
> b <- readRDS("a.RDS")
> b
ff (deleted) integer length=20 (20)
> physical(b)$filename <- "./b.ff"
> b[]
opening ff ./b.ff
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Using `filename()` in the first session would of course have been easier. You could also have a look at the `save.ffdf` and corresponding `load.ffdf` functions in the `ffbase` package, which make this even simpler.

**Addition**

To rename the filenames of all columns in a `ffdf` you can use the following function:

```
redir <- function(ff, newdir) {
  for (x in physical(b)) {
    fn <- basename(filename(x))
    physical(x)$filename <- file.path(newdir, fn)
  }
  return (ff)
}
```

Comment: Yes, Jan, that is correct and works, thanks. But the problem is to move all the "column" vector files included in a ffdf. Of course one could make a function to do that, but it would be good to have a simple physical(ffdf)$filename <- "newfilename" ...

Comment: @MiguelVazq I added a function that renames the filenames of all columns.

Comment: Thanks for the function. I modified a little bit about it, to get correct behavior i needed. This is the function: 
redir <- function(ff, newdir) { nn <- substitute(ff); nn <- all.names(nn); for (x in physical(ff)) { fn <- basename(filename(x)); physical(x)$filename <- file.path(newdir,nn, fn); } return (ff) } . You could perhaps add this one to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ff:::clone()`

```
R> foo <- ff(1:20, vmode = "integer")
R> foo
ff (open) integer length=20 (20)
 [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]      [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    :   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
[20]
  20
R> physical(foo)$filename
[1] "/vol/fftmp/ff69be3e90e728.ff"
R> bar <- clone(foo, pattern = "~/")
R> bar
ff (open) integer length=20 (20)
 [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]      [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    :   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
[20]
  20
R> physical(bar)$filename
[1] "/home/ubuntu/69be5ec0cf98.ff"
```

From what I understand from briefly skimming the code of `save.ffdf` and `load.ffdf`, those functions do this for you when you save/load.

Comment: `clone` creates a copy of the ff-vector; `filename` does a move. If you do a move/copy on the same disk, a move is much faster (might depend on os). In case of the OP's situation where the move/copy is between different disks, the difference is probably negligible.